# Set different static cms block to each different product

Tags: product, static-block, cms-block, magento2.3.3, url-key

I have a created different **CMS static blocks**. I need to call the respective static block for each **product**.

I thought of getting the **URL** key and then assign it to the respective Products.
How could I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: can you please specify the magento version ?

Comment: In Magento CE 2.3.3 @ShashankKumrawat

Comment: @Haerriz you want cms block on product detail page, like while on checkout its shows near add to cart button?  is this you want?

Comment: yes, you are right @MuneshJalwani but every CMS static blocks is related to its relevent products , so its necessary to call the respective static block to its relevent product detail page..

Comment: @Haerriz Check my answer!

Comment: I'm checking on it @MuneshJalwani

Comment: @MuneshJalwani This is not what I asked.
I said that I need to call a CMS static block for each different product.

**For Example:**
In a product page , there will be section of of "Reasons to buy", so for each product the reasons to but gets changed.
Each reasons to buy change for each product.
So each reasons to buy will be made in the static CMS block.
Now How will I assign different static block to each different product?

Answer (score 0):

Best possible solution would be to create static blocks with product skus. Create a template and call these static block in that template and add that template in layout, where you want to place the block.

template will be something like :

```
<?php
 $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
 $_product = $block->getProduct();

?>
<div class="product-block">
 <?php
  echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_product->getSku())->toHtml(); 
  ?>
</div>
```

and place this in your catalog_product_view.xml layout where you want to show the block :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.static.block" as="product_static_block" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_static_block.phtml" />
```

Comment: It says that there's no function named as getSku(). @NaveedAsim

Comment: you should check if sku is visible on listing and product view page

Comment: Sku is visible in product view and in product listing in front end but I phpstorm says that there no function named as getsku(). inside $product @NaveedAsim

Comment: Do I have extend view.php to achieve this answer? @NaveedAsim